# Record From Database is Depend on Paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, paging

```
protected void GridviewArchived_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridviewArchived.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    DisplayArchivedNews();
}

private void DisplayArchivedNews()
{
    using (SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(connection1))
    {
        SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("udspGetArchivedNews", Con);
        Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        Con.Open();
        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Con.Close();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(Cmd);
        da.Fill(ds);
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
        int totalrecord = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
        GridviewArchived.DataSource = ds;
        GridviewArchived.DataBind();
        if (totalrecord > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < totalrecord; i++)
            {
                if( File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~//NewsFolder//Page1//" + GridviewArchived.DataKeys[i].Values["News_ID"].ToString().ToString() + (".PDF"))))
                {
                    HyperLink link = new HyperLink();
                    link.Text = "Page1";
                    link.Target = "blank";
                    link.NavigateUrl = "~//NewsFolder//Page1//" + GridviewArchived.DataKeys[i].Values["News_ID"].ToString() + (".pdf");
                    GridviewArchived.Rows[i].Cells[2].Controls.Add(link);

                }

                }

                }


            }
        }
```

Pagesize is 10, but when total record count is greater than pagesize it throws the following exception:

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index.
```

What is the solution so that record will automatic goes to next pageindex?

Comment: did you add AllowPaging="True" in your gridview in aspx page ?

Answer (score 0):

For showing record of a gridview in paging there are two options for that

One you can add an object datasource with your gridview and show paging through it and the other option is to use jquery Datatable for paging.

Comment: I got the solution, it is  for (int i = 0; i < GridviewArchived.Rows.Count; i++)